# Jekyll - Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- yajl/2.0/yajl

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to get Jekyll working on Windows and am having no luck. This is the first time I've installed/used Ruby.

- **Ruby version**:   ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32] (http://rubyinstaller.org/)
- **Jekyll version**: jekyll 1.0.1

The error goes away when I set pygments to false in `_config.yml`.

**Error message**

```
D:\Code\Jekyll\test>jekyll serve
Configuration file: D:/Code/Jekyll/test/_config.yml
            Source: D:/Code/Jekyll/test
       Destination: D:/Code/Jekyll/test/_site
      Generating...   Liquid Exception: cannot load such file -- yajl/2.0/yajl in 2013-05-11-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl/yajl.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32/lib/yajl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.4.2/lib/pygments/popen.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.4.2/lib/pygments.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:52:in `render_pygments'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb:45:in `render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:106:in `block in render_all'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:93:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:93:in `render_all'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:124:in `render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/liquid-2.5.0/lib/liquid/template.rb:132:in `render!'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:77:in `render_liquid'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:128:in `do_layout'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/post.rb:285:in `render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:230:in `block in render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:229:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:229:in `render'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:44:in `process'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:18:in `process_site'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:23:in `build'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:7:in `process'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.0.1/bin/jekyll:83:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:66:in `run!'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
Build Failed
```

Comment: You might make sure you have run `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`.

Comment: @EricWendelin - Tried this with the gemspec from http://mwmanning.com/2011/11/29/Run-Your-Jekyll-Site-On-Heroku.html and had the same problem after running install :(

Comment: Seems like it is a version compatibility issue: https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby/issues/116

Comment: @scriptin - thanks - I'll try installing an older copy of Ruby to see if that makes a difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was as @scriptin mentioned in the comments.

I installed ruby v 1.9.3 instead and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 12):

I did following

```
gem install rouge
```

and then 
added following line in the  **_config.yml**

```
highlighter: rouge
```

I found this solution from following page's comment thread
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/50

Answer (score 2):

simply add the following line in the **_config.yml**

```
highlighter: false
```

Now browse to localhost:4000

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem today when trying to setup Octopress/Jekyll.

Here is the solution I found.

**Step 1**

Go to your ruby gems directory. 
In my case it's located at `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems`

Look for yajl.

[image: image1]

You will see a folder called `yajl-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32`

You may or may not see one called `yajl-ruby-1.2.1`

The one with a *-ruby-1.1.0-x86-mingw32* tail is the default. And leads to the error.

What we want to use is the other version

**Step 2**

If you do not have the **none** *mingw32* version, run

```
gem install yajl-ruby
```

This will install the latest version.

In my case the latest version was 1.2.1

**Step 3**

Change the default from the *mingw32* version to the current version.

To do so, go to your website's `gemfile.lock` file

Find the line that says `yajl-ruby (1.1.0-x86-mingw32)`

and change it to `yajl-ruby (1.2.1)`

or the respective version you downloaded

[image: img_before]
[image: img_after]

**Step 4**

That's it. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can work round it by manually editing the file that is giving the error to look like this.

RUBY_VERSION =~ /(\d+.\d+)/
require "yajl"

Answer (score 0):

The other proposed solutions appear to either turn off code highlighting, or set it to use Rouge instead of Pygments. I need to use Pygments due to its greater language support.

As described in https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby/issues/116, this issue happens because the precompiled yajl will not work with Ruby 2.0. It needs to be compiled. To make this work so that you can use pygments:

1. Uninstall the precompiled yajl-ruby gem.
2. Install it using the syntax shown in that github thread. Note that you may need to specify the version. In my case, Jekyll specifically wanted 1.1.0, so I installed using this syntax:

gem install yajl-ruby --platform=ruby --version=1.1.0

After doing this, Jekyll worked without disabling code highlighting or switching to Rouge.

Answer (score 0):

Install Yajl 1.2.0. Seems to be a bug with 1.2.1.

```
gem install yajl-ruby --version=1.2.0 --platform=ruby
```

problem solved.

I'm not sure if the platform part is important like others believe, but this worked for me.